# value getText is not a member of type parameter T

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I  receive that error after writing the following line

```
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)
val hashTags = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" ").filter(.startsWith("#")))
```

can anyone help me how to solve it. I dont know if it is because of flatMap function or not but even when I use map function the same error message appear.

Comment: may be you should import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._  , look at this question It has the same case as you

Comment: thank you @Mehrez I  tried that by adding its dependency and it worked